# Object-oriented PHP: Why "this" keyword is a variable?

Tags: php, oop, this

I am learning PHP at the moment and noticed a curious fact from [the tutorial](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php):

> Note: `$this` is a special **variable** that can't be assigned.

Doesen't object that cannot be assigned have to be implemented as ***constant**, not a variable*?

Why it is made so?

Comment: It *is* variable, `$this` always refers to different objects. They could have made it a *magic* constant like `__FILE__`, but they didn't. Meh, that's PHP. It's really the same in many languages, others use `self`, which is indistinguishable from other variables like `foo` as well... Nothing *has* to be implemented a certain way, the language designers can do whatever they want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The scope of a constant is global](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php). In contrast, `$this` changes throughout the application, because it depends on the context (i.e. the class).

Consider this short example:

```
   class A {
       function printThis() { echo $this; }
   }

   class B {
       function printThis() { echo $this; }
   }
```

Clearly, `$this` in `class B` is different from `$this` in `class A`, thus by definition it cannot be a constant*.

*) **Edit:** However, in PHP there exist [magic constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) that change depending on the context:

```
<?php
$line1 =  __LINE__;
$line2 =  __LINE__;
assert($line1 == $line2);  // fails
```

So I think user deceze [summarized it pretty well in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21348497/object-oriented-php-why-this-keyword-is-a-variable#comment32187395_21348497): "*Meh, that's PHP.*"